# You may not specify a referenced group id for an existing IPv4 CIDR rule. prompt when editing the Inbound rule in AWS Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, aws-security-group, ec2-ami

In AWS EC2, I start a Classical Load Balancer in front of EC2 instance (security group of EC2 instance is **launch-wizard-3**).

I want to change the inbound rule of Security Group of EC2 instance . A security group for Classical Load Balancer (its name is **my-first-load-balancer-sg**) was also started. When I am changing source of an inbound rule of **launch-wizard-3** to the **my-first-load-balancer-sg**, following error is prompted.

> You may not specify a referenced group id for an existing IPv4 CIDR rule.

the inbound rule as follows

> (type-HTTP, protocol-TCP, port rang-80, Source type- Custom, Source- **my-first-load-balancer-sg**(what i want to place) )

I tried many times to solve it, but I couldn't.

Comment: try adding a new rule instead, and then removing hte CIDR (eg subnet/ip) based rule afterwards.

Answer (score 316, accepted):

I solved this from deleting the existing rule and creating a new rule

Comment: Fine, but how did you find the existing rule? It doesn't tell you what that is.

Comment: But why must it be this way?  Is Amazon not a billion dollar company that could solve this issue?

Comment: With existing rule you already have a Security group rule ID assigned that is causing problem/conflict. When you create a new rule then this Security group rule ID is not yet assigned. That's why you are not able to edit an existing rule but by creating a new rule works.

Comment: I think the problem might be the fact that the interface is a bit misleading. When I went to edit rules, I thought simply changing the existing default rule (all traffic at all ports originating from the security group) was going to work, but I had to "Add rule" instead.

Answer (score 14):

Simply delete and Add a new rule with the options you require.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

**AWS Database security group configuration**

Please follow the below process:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Delete your second default-created inbound rules and recreate new inbound rules

Answer (score 1):

Your new rule is conflicting with the existing rules, so modify the existing rule or delete and save and then create a new rule altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the existing rule and add a new rule. It would work.